# Tikz - Drawing a partial circle between two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

So I am trying to draw a triangle excircles but I do not need the extra circle beyond the circle's center point. How do I draw the circles partially? Is there any way to cut off the segments?

Here are my current code for the the drawing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,intersections}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bissectrice}{%
    O{}     % drawing options
    mmm     % bissector of mmm
    m       % intersection point between base and bissector
    O{1}O{1}% extended drawing of the bissector
    }{%
    \path[name path=Bis#2#3#4] let
        \p1 = ($(#2) - (#3)$),
        \p2 = ($(#4) - (#3)$),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)/2} ,
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)/2} ,
        \n3 = {max(\n1,\n2)},
        \p1 = ($(#3)!\n3!(#2)$),
        \p2 = ($(#3)!\n3!(#4)$),
        \p3 = ($(\p1) + (\p2) - (#3)$)
    in
        (#3) -- (\p3) ;

    \path[name path = foo] (#2)--(#4) ;

    \path[name intersections={of=foo and Bis#2#3#4, by=#5}] ;

    \path[#1] ($(#3)!#6!(#5)$) -- ($(#5)!#7!(#3)$) ;
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (-3,0);
\coordinate (A1) at (-4,-5);
\coordinate (B) at (4,5);
\coordinate (B1) at (8,10);
\coordinate (B2) at (1,10);
\coordinate (C) at (7,0);
\coordinate (C1) at (10,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (10, -5);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
\draw (A1)--(B1) (B2)--(C2) (C1)--(A2);
\bissectrice {B}{A}{C}{A5};
\bissectrice {A}{B}{C}{B5};
\bissectrice {A}{C}{B}{C5};
\bissectrice {A1}{A}{C}{A3};
\bissectrice {A2}{A}{B}{A4};
\bissectrice {A}{C}{C2}{C3};
\bissectrice {C1}{C}{B}{C4};
\bissectrice {B1}{B}{C}{B3};
\bissectrice {B2}{B}{A}{B4};
\coordinate[label=0:$O_a$] (Oa) at (intersection 1 of A--A3 and C--C3);
\node [draw=black] at (Oa) [circle through={($(A)!(Oa)!(C)$)}]{};
\coordinate[label=-135:$O_b$] (Ob) at (intersection 1 of A--A4 and B4--B);
\node [draw=black] at (Ob) [circle through={($(A)!(Ob)!(B)$)}]{};
\coordinate[label=45:$O_c$] (Oc) at (intersection 1 of B3--B and C--C4);
\node [draw=black] at (Oc) [circle through={($(B)!(Oc)!(C)$)}]{};
\draw (Oa)--node[label=0:$r_a$]{}($(A)!(Oa)!(C)$) (Ob)--node[label=45:$r_b$]{}($(A)!(Ob)!(B)$) (Oc)--node[label=90:$r_c$]{}($(B)!(Oc)!(C)$);
\coordinate (O) at (intersection 1 of A5--A and B5--B);
\draw (O)-- node[label=right:$r$]{}($(A)!(O)!(C)$);
\node [draw=black] at (O) [circle through={($(A)!(O)!(C)$)}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Drawing that I have:

[image: current drawing]

Drawing that I want:

[image]

Comment: You can look at [tkz-euclide](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) for this kind of diagrams. It's written in french but commands and  examples are easy to understand.

Comment: Would you mind to compose a complete compilable document? From your code I had to copy two code fragments, compoun them into a new document  and add `intersections`, `calc` and `through` tikzlibraries which were not mentioned in your question. And sorry, but even after that I don't clearly understand what's the problem.

Comment: It would be hard for me to copy down the entire document as the whole thing is about 300 line, and I am certainly new to writing in TeX. Sorry if it was confusing and unclear. I have added more details just now.

Comment: `\clip` can certainly help.

Comment: I took the liberty of making a single piece of code that can be compiled directly, and produces the drawing. This is what @Ignasi meant by a complete document, not the whole thing, but enough that it can copy-pasted into an editor and compiled without making modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Torbjørn suggested, you can `clip` the whole diagram. I did it with a rectangle base on `A1` and `B1`:

```
\clip ([shift={(-2,-2)}]A1) rectangle ([shift={(3,-2)}]B1);
```

but you can select another clipping path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,intersections}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bissectrice}{%
    O{}     % drawing options
    mmm     % bissector of mmm
    m       % intersection point between base and bissector
    O{1}O{1}% extended drawing of the bissector
    }{%
    \path[name path=Bis#2#3#4] let
        \p1 = ($(#2) - (#3)$),
        \p2 = ($(#4) - (#3)$),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)/2} ,
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)/2} ,
        \n3 = {max(\n1,\n2)},
        \p1 = ($(#3)!\n3!(#2)$),
        \p2 = ($(#3)!\n3!(#4)$),
        \p3 = ($(\p1) + (\p2) - (#3)$)
    in
        (#3) -- (\p3) ;

    \path[name path = foo] (#2)--(#4) ;

    \path[name intersections={of=foo and Bis#2#3#4, by=#5}] ;

    \path[#1] ($(#3)!#6!(#5)$) -- ($(#5)!#7!(#3)$) ;
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (-3,0);
\coordinate (A1) at (-4,-5);
\coordinate (B) at (4,5);
\coordinate (B1) at (8,10);
\coordinate (B2) at (1,10);
\coordinate (C) at (7,0);
\coordinate (C1) at (10,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (10, -5);
\clip ([shift={(-2,-2)}]A1) rectangle ([shift={(3,-2)}]B1);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
\draw (A1)--(B1) (B2)--(C2) (C1)--(A2);
\bissectrice {B}{A}{C}{A5};
\bissectrice {A}{B}{C}{B5};
\bissectrice {A}{C}{B}{C5};
\bissectrice {A1}{A}{C}{A3};
\bissectrice {A2}{A}{B}{A4};
\bissectrice {A}{C}{C2}{C3};
\bissectrice {C1}{C}{B}{C4};
\bissectrice {B1}{B}{C}{B3};
\bissectrice {B2}{B}{A}{B4};
\coordinate[label=0:$O_a$] (Oa) at (intersection 1 of A--A3 and C--C3);
\node [draw=black] at (Oa) [circle through={($(A)!(Oa)!(C)$)}]{};
\coordinate[label=-135:$O_b$] (Ob) at (intersection 1 of A--A4 and B4--B);
\node [draw=black] at (Ob) [circle through={($(A)!(Ob)!(B)$)}]{};
\coordinate[label=45:$O_c$] (Oc) at (intersection 1 of B3--B and C--C4);
\node [draw=black] at (Oc) [circle through={($(B)!(Oc)!(C)$)}]{};
\draw (Oa)--node[label=0:$r_a$]{}($(A)!(Oa)!(C)$) (Ob)--node[label=45:$r_b$]{}($(A)!(Ob)!(B)$) (Oc)--node[label=90:$r_c$]{}($(B)!(Oc)!(C)$);
\coordinate (O) at (intersection 1 of A5--A and B5--B);
\draw (O)-- node[label=right:$r$]{}($(A)!(O)!(C)$);
\node [draw=black] at (O) [circle through={($(A)!(O)!(C)$)}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]