# How to draw excircles of a triangle by TikZ code not tkz-euclide?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw all the excircles of a triangle by TikZ code. I already found how to draw it by tkz-euclide. I have read the PGF manual. But I didn't find any way to draw excircles. Can you tell me?

Comment: Which step are you having trouble with? The math or the TikZ code?

Comment: I know how the math. I want to kmow the TikZ code.

Comment: Okay, which part is giving you trouble? Drawing three lines and three circles is not hard if you know the coordinates. It's just like `\draw (1,0) -- (2,5); \draw (3,3) circle (4);`. Maybe it would help if you provided a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)) which shows where you need help.

Comment: Actually if tjere is a way to draw a circle which is tangent to three given lines then we are done. But how? Take any triangle as example

Comment: TikZ does not have a built-in way to calculate tangents of circles, or circles which are tangent to given lines. If you want to calculate that circle using pure TikZ, you have to write the formulas yourself using the pgfmath macros. That is what `tkz-euclide` does (I guess, I haven't used it myselfm but I have used TikZ quite extensively).

Comment: Why don't you want to use `tkz-euclide`? `tkz-euclide` commands are compatible with `tikz` ones, so you can add one `tkz-euclide` command while keeping all other drawing commands in `tikz` syntax.

Comment: Maybe here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316962/tikz-drawing-a-partial-circle-between-two-lines